# Упразднить псевдокласс :hover с помощью CSS

Tags: css, hover

Добрый день! Есть выпадающее меню,  которое реализуется так:

```
.menu:hover > .sub_menu{
    display:block;
}
```

В мобильной версии сайта, выпадающее меню хочу реализовать через клик. Чтобы отменить эффект `hover` по медиа-запросу, в соседних темах советуют сделать так:

```
.menu:hover > .sub_menu{
    display:none;
}
```

Но данная конструкция не отменяет `hover`, а переопределяет его. В итоге имеем такую ситуацию, когда меню раскрывается по клику, а если увести мышку с меню и завести обратно, то срабатывает `display:none`. Хотелось бы избежать такой ситуации и просто упразднить эффект `hover`. Можно ли так сделать на CSS не задействуя JS?

Comment: У тебя на мобильнике `hover` сработает как `click`....

Comment: @Air ну, я пока только на ноуте тестю)

Comment: А ты на мобильнике попробуй))))

Comment: @Air не, ну `hover` - это `mouseenter` - он на `click` и не будет срабатывать). Речь-то о другом. Что и `click`  и `hover` - будут работать вместе и иметь противоположные эффекты.

Comment: Я тебя понял....

Comment: @Air, открыл с телефона - а там `hover` работает как `click` оказывается) Мдя...)

Comment: Ну и отлично...)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте стили для ховера, тоже в медиа запросах. Тогда на мобильных они не будут срабатывать

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .menu:hover > .sub_menu{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Идея понятна, спасибо. Но хотелось бы более глобально решить вопрос,  что-то типа `hover: none`  и все)

Comment: ну нет, о таких не знаю.... 
ну сами подумайте, вы задаёте стиль a { color: red }. А потом хотите убрать этот стиль? не переназначить, а именно отменить, как будто его и не было. Это как?... Ну тоже и с ховером

Comment: `color: none` - нет?)

Comment: это переназначения стиля